# Creating UFField using API - error with field_name

Tags: api, migration

I'm trying to migrate data using the API and I'm having issues with UFField. Some entries are inserted correctly while others give me the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught API_Exception: [0]: The field_name is not valid`

`thrown in /.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFField.php on line 61`

This happens whether I'm using a field that exists after installing CiviCRM such as participant_status or whether I use custom groups. I have already migrated all UFGroup and CustomGroup entries and corresponding custom group tables were created without issue.

What does field_name even refer to? I can't seem to find any info in the documentation and by looking through the database or API. Any help?

I am using CiviCRM version 5.46.2 on Wordpress.

Comment: Are you migrating CiviCRM database to a different solution ?

Comment: I am migrating from a Drupal instance of CiviCRM to a Wordpress instance, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: you don't have to migrate the data you can convert the database - https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switching-cms/drupal-to-wordpress/